# default print settings distribution

Tags: windows-server-2003, printing

If i change the default settings of a printer on the server when do these take effect on a users computer?

I've done some testing but couldn't really figure it out, sometimes it changes after logging off and on but sometimes i doesn't and after a while it's suddenly ok. I've even seen it change while i was still logged on.

So is there a constant when the server sends an update out, like every 15min,... and if so is there way to trigger this event?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean printers shared via a Windows printer server, then the default printer settings are configured on the server side.

Bring up the *Properties* of the printer you want to configure and select the *Advanced* tab.  There is a button labeled *Printing Defaults*.  This will allow you to configure the defaults for this printer.  End users will still be able to configure their individual print jobs to use different settings if they wish.  This will, however, set the defaults for all users.

[image: Printing Defaults]

The settings take effect immediately. They do not need to propagate.

If users are granted the *Manage Printers* right in a printer's ACL, they will be able to alter these server-side defaults -- you probably don't want this.  Typically *Manage Documents* is more than enough.